# Summarise number of types with two columns?

Tags: r

I've been trying to summarise a dataset I have:

`Car / Number: "Mercedes" 4 observations. "Volvo" 3 observations. "Toyota" 7 observations. "Ford" 2 observations. "Volvo" 1 observations. "Toyota" 2 observations. "..." X observations.`

I've been trying different types of summarising functions without results, e.g.
`summarise(count = car * number)` without any success. The goal is to summarise the top 5 car types in a table.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: `dplyr::count(df, car)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try a `group_by()` and `summarise()` approach from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

cars %>%
   group_by(car) %>%
   summarise(Count = n() %>%
   arrange(desc(Count)
```

That should provide a list of each car type sorted in descending order of their count.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a data set to show it

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$model <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), `[[`, 1)
```

The solution: count the car models with `table`, `sort` it, and return only the top 5 (`head`).

```r
head(sort(table(mtcars$model), decreasing = TRUE))
#> 
#>   Merc   Fiat Hornet  Mazda Toyota    AMC 
#>      7      2      2      2      2      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>